# Spring Boot gRPC API unable to start Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a single module spring gRPC project. I have written the .proto files I am able to compile the project and generate the necessary files. However when I try to run the project I get an error starting tomcat.

Here is my properties file...

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/protodb'
    username: root
    password: 35581277mM/

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
  hibernate:
    ddl-auto: update
  properties:
    hibernate:
      dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

  server:
    port: '9191'

  grpc:
    port: '8080'
    enableReflection: true
```

And my pom file looks like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.maddennis</groupId>
    <artifactId>grpcscuffhold</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>grpcscuffhold</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot grpc scuffhold</description>

    <properties>
        <protobuf.version>3.22.3</protobuf.version>
        <protobuf-plugin.version>0.6.1</protobuf-plugin.version>
        <grpc.version>1.54.1</grpc.version>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.devh/grpc-server-spring-boot-starter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-server-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Java 9+ compatibility - Do NOT update to 2.0.0 -->
            <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${protobuf-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:${protobuf.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpc.version}:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is the error I am getting...

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin\java.exe" -javaagent:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\231.8770.65\lib\idea_rt.jar=53664:C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\IDEA-C\ch-0\231.8770.65\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\user\Downloads\grpcscuffhold\grpcscuffhold\target\classes;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-web-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.0.6\spring-boot-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.0.6\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.7\logback-classic-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.7\logback-core-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.19.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.19.0\log4j-api-2.19.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.7\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-json-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.14.2\jackson-databind-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.14.2\jackson-annotations-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.14.2\jackson-core-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.14.2\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.14.2\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.14.2\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.14.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.8\spring-web-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.8\spring-beans-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.10.6\micrometer-observation-1.10.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.10.6\micrometer-commons-1.10.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.0.8\spring-webmvc-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.8\spring-aop-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.8\spring-context-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.8\spring-expression-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.19\aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.8\spring-jdbc-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.1.7.Final\hibernate-core-6.1.7.Final.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\jboss\jandex\2.4.2.Final\jandex-2.4.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.12.23\byte-buddy-1.12.23.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.2\jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.2\jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.0\angus-activation-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.2\txw2-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.0\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10.1\antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.0.5\spring-data-jpa-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.0.5\spring-data-commons-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.8\spring-orm-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.8\spring-tx-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.7\slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.8\spring-aspects-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\3.0.6\spring-boot-starter-validation-3.0.6.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\8.0.0.Final\hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\3.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\net\devh\grpc-server-spring-boot-starter\2.14.0.RELEASE\grpc-server-spring-boot-starter-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\net\devh\grpc-server-spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.14.0.RELEASE\grpc-server-spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\net\devh\grpc-common-spring-boot\2.14.0.RELEASE\grpc-common-spring-boot-2.14.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-core\1.51.0\grpc-core-1.51.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.9.1\gson-2.9.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\android\annotations\4.1.1.4\annotations-4.1.1.4.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\mojo\animal-sniffer-annotations\1.21\animal-sniffer-annotations-1.21.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-netty-shaded\1.51.0\grpc-netty-shaded-1.51.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\perfmark\perfmark-api\0.25.0\perfmark-api-0.25.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-services\1.51.0\grpc-services-1.51.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java-util\3.21.7\protobuf-java-util-3.21.7.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-api\1.51.0\grpc-api-1.51.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-context\1.51.0\grpc-context-1.51.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.0.33\mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.26\lombok-1.18.26.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.8\spring-core-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.8\spring-jcl-6.0.8.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-stub\1.54.1\grpc-stub-1.54.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\31.1-android\guava-31.1-android.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.12.0\checker-qual-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\1.3\j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.18.0\error_prone_annotations-2.18.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf\1.54.1\grpc-protobuf-1.54.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\protobuf\protobuf-java\3.21.7\protobuf-java-3.21.7.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\com\google\api\grpc\proto-google-common-protos\2.9.0\proto-google-common-protos-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\io\grpc\grpc-protobuf-lite\1.54.1\grpc-protobuf-lite-1.54.1.jar;C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\1.3.5\jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar io.maddennis.grpcscuffhold.GrpcApp

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.6)

2023-05-08T11:13:32.586+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] io.maddennis.grpcscuffhold.GrpcApp       : Starting GrpcApp using Java 19.0.1 with PID 16436 (C:\Users\user\Downloads\grpcscuffhold\grpcscuffhold\target\classes started by user in C:\Users\user\Downloads\grpcscuffhold\grpcscuffhold)
2023-05-08T11:13:32.588+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] io.maddennis.grpcscuffhold.GrpcApp       : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-08T11:13:33.217+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-08T11:13:33.277+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 51 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-08T11:13:33.830+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-08T11:13:33.838+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-08T11:13:33.839+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-05-08T11:13:33.904+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-08T11:13:33.909+03:00  INFO 16436 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1268 ms
2023-05-08T11:13:33.959+03:00 ERROR 16436 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [requestContextFilter]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.findPostConstruct(DefaultInstanceManager.java:639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:156) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4305) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4918) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:488) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at io.maddennis.grpcscuffhold.GrpcApp.main(GrpcApp.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 43 common frames omitted

2023-05-08T11:13:33.963+03:00 ERROR 16436 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [Tomcat WebSocket (JSR356) Filter]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.findPostConstruct(DefaultInstanceManager.java:639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:156) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4305) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4918) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:485) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:488) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:210) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:183) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:161) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1304) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1293) ~[spring-boot-3.0.6.jar:3.0.6]
    at io.maddennis.grpcscuffhold.GrpcApp.main(GrpcApp.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct
    ... 43 common frames omitted

2023-05-08T11:13:33.965+03:00 ERROR 16436 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Exception starting filter [characterEncodingFilter]

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/annotation/PostConstruct
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.findPostConstruct(DefaultInstanceManager.java:639) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:163) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:156) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4305) ~[tomcat-
    
    



Process finished with exit code 1
```

My project structure looks like this...

I have tried to look up the exceptions but I really do not know where the error could be coming from